Patrol Instrumentation Tests Setup in Flutter: Getting Errors on Import and Package Name Mismatch
I'm trying to set up Patrol E2E tests in a Flutter app. The setup is mostly correct, but I'm running into issues with the MainActivityTest imports and package name mismatch errors. I'm following the official documentation, but the tests are not running as expected.
[https://patrol.leancode.co/documentation][1]
Ran the following commands to install Patrol CLI:
flutter pub global activate patrol_cli
patrol doctor
flutter pub add patrol --dev

dev_dependencies:
patrol: ^latest_version
patrol:
app_name: App
android:
package_name: com.ziing.app
Created the test file MainActivityTest.java under android/app/src/androidTest/java/com/ziing/app/:
package com.ziing.app;
import androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import pl.leancode.patrol.PatrolJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class MainActivityTest {

    @Parameterized.Parameters(name = "{0}")
    public static Object[] testCases() {
        PatrolJUnitRunner instrumentation = (PatrolJUnitRunner) InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation();
        instrumentation.setUp(MainActivity.class);
        instrumentation.waitForPatrolAppService();
        return instrumentation.listDartTests();
    }

    private final String dartTestName;

    public MainActivityTest(String dartTestName) {
        this.dartTestName = dartTestName;
    }

    @Test
    public void runDartTest() {
        PatrolJUnitRunner instrumentation = (PatrolJUnitRunner) InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation();
        instrumentation.runDartTest(dartTestName);
    }
}

Added the following to the defaultConfig section
testInstrumentationRunner "pl.leancode.patrol.PatrolJUnitRunner"
testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: "true"
Added this to the android section:
gradle
testOptions {
    execution "ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR"
}

Added the orchestrator dependency:
gradle
androidTestUtil "androidx.test:orchestrator:1.5.1"

Despite following all the steps as outlined in the Patrol documentation, I’m seeing the following import-related errors:
Missing Imports:
package pl.leancode.patrol does not exist
package androidx.test.platform.app does not exist
package org.junit does not exist

What I Have Tried:
Checked Dependencies: I’ve verified that all dependencies (Patrol, AndroidX Test, JUnit) are correctly added to the build.gradle and pubspec.yaml files.
Rebuilt Project: Cleaned and rebuilt the project, but the errors persist.
Synced Gradle: Ran flutter pub get and re-synced the Gradle project.
Flutter Clean: Executed flutter clean and then tried rebuilding the project.
Requesting for help
